# upload the file and submit form using CURL in puppet module

Tags: curl, puppet

I have a curl command to upload a file and submit the form.

```
curl --form <file>=@<filename> --form press=<value>  [URL]
```

need to write a puppet execution block as below .

```
ex: exec { "IngestClient $abc_name" :

    command => "curl --form file=@$file --form press=Submit  http://ipaddress:portno/myapp/abc/"
    cwd     => "$data/bin",
    path    => "$data/bin:/usr/bin",
    require => [File["$package_file"],Package['curl']],
}
```

I need to parameterize the url and file name and  file and button value.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Then I suggest you do just that. ;-p But jokes aside, it is not quite clear what you are getting at. Please clarify your question.

Comment: need to parametrize the URL.Instead hardcoding the url.

Answer (score 1):

you could define a custom type with parameters `filename`, `url`, `abc_name`, `data` and `package_file`:

```
define uploadFile(
    $filename     = $title,
    $url          = undef,
    $abc_name     = undef,
    $data         = undef,
    $package_file = undef
) {
    exec { "IngestClient ${abc_name}" :

        command => "curl --form file=@${filename} --form press=Submit  ${url}"
        cwd     => "${data}/bin",
        path    => "${data}/bin:/usr/bin",
        require => [ File["${package_file}"], Package['curl'] ]
    } 
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
uploadFile { "my-file":
    url          => "http://ipaddress:portno/myapp/abc",
    abc_name     => "???",
    data         => "/foo/bar",
    package_file => "???"
}
```